# IronPython3 Host throws "TypeErrorException: metaclass conflict" when inheriting from a .net class

Tags: python, c#, .net, ironpython

I have the following C# type:

```
[PythonType]
public class ScriptBase
{
    public virtual int TestMe()
    {
        return 11;
    }
}
```

Then, I'm trying to create a class that inherits from `ScriptBase` in python:

```
from Base import ScriptBase

class TestClass (ScriptBase):
    pass
```

Trying to execute this script yields:
`TypeErrorException: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases`

This is how I'm creating the engine and registering the type:

```
// Executed to test
ScriptEngine _engine = Python.CreateEngine();

// Create base module
ScriptScope _gameScope = _engine.CreateModule("Base");

// Expose ScriptBase class in the module
_gameScope.SetVariable(nameof(ScriptBase), typeof(ScriptBase));

// Load the source from a file stream through a wrapper and compile
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSource(new CodeProvider(inStream), package, Encoding.ASCII, SourceCodeKind.Statements);
CompiledCode compiled = source.Compile();

// Create new module for the inheriting classes
_scope = engine.CreateModule(package);

// Execute the code -- this line throws an exception
compiled.Execute(_scope);
```

I've tried importing CLR and defining both `__init__` and `__new__`, this changes nothing. The `.CreateModule` approach works for instantiating and managing existing types, it's just the inheritance part that seems broken - is there any step that I'm missing?

I'm not very proficient with python, so I'm not sure what this message complains about. I've tried numerous approaches found online, but always seem to end up in the same place.

The runtime is mono, targeting .Net 4.x. Here's the full callstack.

```
TypeErrorException: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
IronPython.Runtime.Types.PythonType.FindMetaClass (IronPython.Runtime.Types.PythonType cls, IronPython.Runtime.PythonTuple bases) (at <57a5bd653356491bba8a61ecf9211193>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.MakeClass (IronPython.Runtime.FunctionCode funcCode, System.Func`2[T,TResult] body, IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext parentContext, System.String name, IronPython.Runtime.PythonTuple bases, IronPython.Runtime.PythonDictionary keywords, System.String selfNames) (at <57a5bd653356491bba8a61ecf9211193>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`8[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet].Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) (at <9784853821ea47dbb6bb1f3e03091049>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) (at <9784853821ea47dbb6bb1f3e03091049>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet] (T0 arg0, T1 arg1) (at <9784853821ea47dbb6bb1f3e03091049>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext ctx) (at <57a5bd653356491bba8a61ecf9211193>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <57a5bd653356491bba8a61ecf9211193>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <57a5bd653356491bba8a61ecf9211193>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <57a5bd653356491bba8a61ecf9211193>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.CompiledCode.Execute (Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope scope) (at <0d164baeace648b2930cfd25249cf9f3>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.CompiledCode.Execute(Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to find the solution myself after going through IronPython source code (thank you good people for open source software, your work is appreciated).

It turns out that to properly expose a .net `Type` to IronPython world is through `DynamicHelpers.GetPythonTypeFromType(System.Type)`. I'm currently using this extension method to register my types in a `ScriptScope`:

```
public static void RegisterType(this ScriptScope self, Type t) =>
    self.SetVariable(t.Name, DynamicHelpers.GetPythonTypeFromType(t));
```

Hope this helps somebody.